# How to get user data in AWS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I'm trying to make a simple (React) website where a user signs in and it gets their data from a MySQL database and displays it in a table on the website. The flow is like this:

Home Page -> Sign In -> App

I want to show the user's data that is stored in a AWS RDS (MySQL) when they log into the App.

I have the domain and static hosting set up. I have a user pool set up in AWS Cognito. I set up an API Gateway with authorization and connected a basic lambda function to it. When the user signs in the are redirected to the App page with a JWT token in the header. I don't know where to go from here.

This is what I'm thinking:

- User logs in, redirected to callback URL with JWT token in header.
- Get the JWT token, decode it and get the user email
- In my Lambda function, connect to the database instance (AWS RDS)
- To query user data, select user data from a table whose name is the
  users email

I don't know how to do any of the above though (apart from SQL queries). Are these even the correct steps?

How do I get the JWT token in my code? From what I know it has to be passed with every API call? I have my invoke URL from API Gateway, how do I send a request with the JWT token?

What would the database instance look like? Would it be a collection of tables that each represent a user?

How do I do this with and without AWS Amplify?

I've been trying for a few weeks but there's so much info and I feel like I'm over complicating something that is very simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the **AWS SDK for JavaScript** to query data on the backend and a React front end that displays the data.

This use case is located in the AWS Code Lib here:

[Create an Aurora Serverless work item tracker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_RDSDataTracker_javascript_3_topic.html)

This example shows how to use the **AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3)** to create a web application that tracks work items in an Amazon Aurora database and emails reports by using Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES). This example uses a front end built with React.js to interact with an Express Node.js backend.
Services used in this example

AWS Services used in this example:

- Aurora
- Amazon RDS
- Amazon RDS Data Service
- Amazon SES

Note that this example focuses on the AWS SDK, such as the **RDSDataClient**)  and not stuff like JWT tokens, Amplify etc